# How to disable/hide all the activities during an Overview in Gnome?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, activities-overview

In GNOME, when an Overview is triggered, you are presented with all the windows currently open in the workspace.

This causes sudden CPU usage spikes (and temperature spikes on hot days) and `gnome-shell` becomes sluggish for a while. It is very easy to ignore the CPU and temperature spikes, but the single-digit frame-rate of animation bothers me enough to become annoyed. I can't turn off animations because they really help me with spatial awareness of windows.

**Is there a way to prevent Overview from showing me the floating window previews?** Because this is the only animation that is taxing enough on my CPU.

---

### What would be nice

An extension that just opens the blank Overview (as if I just logged in and I haven't opened any windows). That way, I can proceed to type something in search box and launch an application, without seeing any window-previews before I begin typing.

---

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

---

#### EDIT

Before suggesting to disable all the animations, please understand that I really need the rest of the animations. They help me with spatial awareness of workspaces and windows.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a valid answer per se, but a workaround until a real solution is found.

Just install the extension [Start Overlay in Applications View](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1198/start-overlay-in-application-view/). Now, whenever you press <kbd>Super</kbd>, Overview will open by default in Applications view (as if launched by <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, assuming default shortcuts). Now the CPU spikes and UI sluggishness will very less compared to stock.

### ISSUES

1. There is quite a noticeable delay in actual appearance of the overview.
   But it's not much of a problem because once you have pressed <kbd>Super</kbd>, you can just start typing the name of application you want to launch (even though the actual overview will be visible after a delay). All the typed letters will be caught by the overview when it is finally visible.
2. Sometimes when you open the Overview, all the icons will do the animation thingy... which again causes CPU spikes.

---

Come on! Someone please write an extension for blank overview!!!

Comment: You can install the extensions "Hide Activities Button" or "Remove activities Button" if you want to remove entirely and not only with blank overview.

Comment: @Mak.K I don't think you understand... that's not gonna work. Because a guy needs to launch some apps right? He has to press the `Super` and start typing to launch apps, right? Unless you have "Dash to Panel" extension installed, of course, then you can ditch the overview entirely... ;-)